# How to get the Chart.js type information into my plain javascript file using JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, types, chart.js, jsdoc

I can't seem to get JSDoc-based intellisense in VSCode to work for the Chart.js library.

### Reproducible scenario

The steps are minimal and detailed below, but you can also [clone my repository](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/repro-chartjs-with-jsdoc) created with the steps from this question.

I have a rather old application, here's a minimally reproducible variant of what I have:

- Run `npm i chart.js chartjs-adapter-moment moment`
- Create an `index.html` like this:

```html
<html>
  <script src="node_modules/moment/moment.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.umd.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/chartjs-adapter-moment/dist/chartjs-adapter-moment.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <div style="height: 200px; width: 300px;"><canvas id="my-chart"></canvas></div>
</html>
```

- Create an `app.js` file like this:

```javascript
// @ts-check

/**
 * @typedef moment
 * @property {import('moment')} moment
 */

/**
 * @global {import('chart.js')} Chart
 */

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const ctx = document.getElementById("my-chart");
  const chartRef = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    options: {
      scales: {
        x: { type: "time" },
        y: { min: 0, max: 10 },
      },
    },
    data: {
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Stuff',
          data: [
            { x: moment("2023-01-01"), y: 2 },
            { x: moment("2023-02-01"), y: 8 },
            { x: moment("2023-03-01"), y: 3 },
            { x: moment("2023-04-01"), y: 6 },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  });
});
```

### The problem

The `moment` types seem to be working well in VSCode. But the `Chart` typings are not working at all. Here's what it does in VSCode currently:

[image: error tooltip over 'Chart']

I've tried a bunch of different things instead of the `@global` declaration, nothing seems to work.

### Bottom line / The question

How do I properly get the type completion for Chart.js `Chart` and related types in VSCode when I'm not using any `import` or `require` or similar?

---

### Things I've tried

A helpful answer appeared but I can add the suggestions from it to the "things I've tried", but they don't fix my specific issue as detailed below.

The first suggestion was to use `/** @typedef {import("chart.js")} */` but that leaves me with the same error:

> Cannot find name 'Chart'. ts(2304)

[image: Screenshot showing the error from above]

As I wrote in my comment to the answer at some point I think I also saw:

> 'Chart' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. ts(2693)

But I must've gotten that on a slight variation to the suggestion, and can't seem to get that specific error now anymore.

An edit to the question was made to suggest trying `/** @typedef {import("chart.js").Chart} Chart */` which *does* give me:

> 'Chart' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. ts(2693)

As you can tell from the corresponding screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the error detailed above]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `@global` to `/** @typedef {import("chart.js")} */`.

See also https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html for the list of supported JSDoc things. I don't see `@global` in there. VS Code's builtin JS support is built on TypeScript's tsserver.

If you want a specific type, then [import the type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#import-types): `/** @typedef {import("chart.js").Chart} Chart */`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It leaves me with one more problem to solve though, as it changes the error hovering over "_Chart" to the message "'Chart' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. ts(2693)_". I presume that's because of the way `Chart` is exported from the library?

Comment: Thx again for your continued help! However, that also still gives me troubles I've extensively updated my question with a "things I've tried" section detailing your suggestions, with screenshots of the failed outcome. - You seemed confident in your suggestions so perhaps I'm doing something subtly wrong? So I've also added a GitHub repository with the exact reproducible scenario that should give all these exact errors I have.